# C# YouTube Data API v3 sample is returning Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: c#, youtube-data-api, google-oauth

I am trying to upload videos on YouTube using the [.NET Code Samples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video) created by Google. I also have downloaded the sample code from [github repository](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/dotnet) of Google and used the `client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris` etc. by following their instructions. I tried this one from `C#` console application in `localhost`, webforms application in `localhost` and in production, but all of them are returning the same error with different `port number` each time.

Please see the images for more details:

Error 1 with a port number:

[image: Error 1 with a port number]

Error 2 with a different port number:

[image: Error 2 with a different port number]

Client ID setup for Web application in Google Console:

[image: Client ID setup for Web application in Google Console]

Client ID and Secrects in my application:

[image: Client ID and Secrects in my application]

Comment: 'localhost' is not the same as 127.0.0.1. Have you tried adding 127.0.0.1 to you list of authorized redirect URIs?

Comment: Wow, it's working with http://127.0.0.1:50499/. I never thought that localhost is not same as http://127.0.0.1:50499/ !  Thank you very much @zeroef